# How to write/append PING results to output file

Tags: python, python-3.x, output, ping

Fairly new to Python so forgive the basic question and my repetitive coding.  I'm trying to write a script that PINGs a network segment then writes the results to a couple of TXT files.

I have the PING scan part working just fine with some code I found online, just cant get the results to save in the files. The files get created but they are blank.

Can someone check this out and give me some recommendations?

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
import subprocess
import ipaddress

# Prompt the user to input a network address
network = input("Enter a network address in CIDR format(ex.192.168.1.0/24): ")

# Create the network
ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(network)

# Get all hosts on that network
all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())

# Create output file in preset directory
os.chdir("C:\\Python364\\Output")
onlineHosts = "Online_Hosts.txt"
offlineHosts = "Offline_Hosts.txt"
on  = open(onlineHosts, 'a') # File object 'on' is created with append mode
off = open(offlineHosts, 'a') # File object 'off' is created with append mode

# Configure subprocess to hide the console window
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

# For each IP address in the subnet, 
# run the ping command with subprocess.popen interface
for i in range(len(all_hosts)):
    output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '500', str(all_hosts[i])], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=info).communicate()[0]

    if "Destination host unreachable" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Offline")
        result = str(all_hosts[i])
        off.write(result)

    elif "Request timed out" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Offline")
        result = str(all_hosts[i])
        off.write(result)
    else:
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Online")
        result = str(all_hosts[i])
        on.write(result
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to close the files when finished with them. The writing may stay in the buffer until you do.

on.close()

off.close()

To write immediately without closing, you can flush the buffers:

on.flush()

off.flush()

Comment: When I add the following code, I get an I/O Error as it runs the PING.

Comment: Did you try to write to the files again after closing them? You should only close a file after you are completely done with it. Otherwise, to write out immediately, use flush.

Comment: result = str(all_hosts[i])
        off.write(result)
        off.close()
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Offline")

Comment: sorry the formatting on the comment isn't what I expected.

Comment: If that’s in your for loop, then you should use flush, because after you close a file you can’t write to it again unless you open it again. If you absolutely have to write to the file after every iteration of the loop, replace “close()” with “flush()”. Otherwise, call close once on each file after your for loop finishes executing.

Comment: I tried the *.flush() and it worked.  The output is now in 2 files.  Just need to work on the formatting so it's not strung together.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

If one only want to use the shell, I found the following to be helpful for this problem: https://ss64.com/nt/type.html

To write the ping results to the output file, type:

```
ping -t "SomeIPAddress" > newfile.txt
```

To append ping results to the existing output file, type:

```
ping -t "some IP address" >> existingfile.txt
```

If you also want to add a timestamp on the ping results, then you can type the following in the Powershell:

```
ping -t "SomeIPAddress"|Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} > > newfile.txt
```

Source: https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Ping-Test-and-save-to-text-file?language=en_US